# Do JavaScript class instances clone functions?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, instance

If i have the following code:

```
function myClass(){
    this.type = 1;
    this.ret = function(){
        return this.type;
    }
}

var ins1 = new myClass,
    ins2 = new myClass,
    ins3 = new myClass;

ins2.type = 2;
ins3.type = 3;

console.log(ins1.ret() + ' - ' + ins2.ret() + ' - ' + ins3.ret());
```

The output in the console is

`1 - 2 - 3`

When the code runs (the `console.log()` part), is there one method `ret()` running, or three? If each instance creates a new method, how can I avoid that? If they all do the same exact thing, why have three of them.

Comment: There are three different methods running, because you are creating a NEW myclass. If you want to avoid them, you shouldn't create three instance you can do  singleton.

Comment: I want to have three different "type" variables, one is equal to 1, the other is equal to 2 and the third is 3. But I want each instance of the class to use one method. How?

Comment: you can define the ret function in the prototype of the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods are different indeed. You are wasting memory.

```
ins1.ret == ins2.ret; // false
```

Instead, you can define the method in the prototype:

```
function myClass(){}
myClass.prototype.type = 1;
myClass.prototype.ret = function(){
  return this.type;
};
```